# Riggin my character deformes him

Tags: rigging, armature

Here is the File http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35751
My question is about rigging , Long story short, I'm new to blender and i finished my latest model and began to rigging it (First time doing so) Followed the tutorial to the letter and when I flip the armature (Left side of it) the elbows off,[image] no problems with the leg, so I fix it,[image] [image] [image: Edit Mode][image: Pose Mode]but when I sent automatic weights the whole arm and shoulder part are F'ed up, No idea why. [image][image]
Can anyone help?  Here is the File http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35751

Also I have an alienware computer and not a particularly cheap one, And I've never really had lagg issues in blender up until I connected the facial features to the face, now whenever I click on anything it take a good 10 seconds to register, Is this just me making models with bad topology or is there a way to maximize processing speed after the models done and you want to do things with it.

Comment: If you have a question about toon shading in cycles, that should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Im sorry I cant explain my problem better I can upload the file if you want to take a look at it, I tried the fix and i'm getting the same issue. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35751

Comment: @Steven  You need to apply the pose to rest position first then you can bind the mesh to your armature.

Comment: @Denis Can you elaborate on that? What do you mean rest position? the bones are in the place i want them in both pose and edit mode before I bind the two and it still give me issues with the arms and shoulders :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the deformation when binding the mesh to armature you need to apply the pose to **Rest position**. Change to **Pose Mode**, then select all the bones and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut and select **Apply Pose as Rest Pose**. Then Change to Object Mode, select your mesh then the armature and parent with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> shortcut.

[image]

Comment: HECK YEAH! (monitoring my language cause I dunno this sites policies) Thank you guys! It worked! I really appreciate it!